# How to use ComboBox in jList

Tags: java, swing, combobox, jlist

I want to use combobox as an element of `jList`. I wrote this following code but it didn't work.

```
AbstractListModel listmodel = new AbstractListModel() {
    Object [] objects = all_objects; //all_objects contains ComboBox and Strings
        public int getSize() {
            return objects.length;
        }

        public Object getElementAt(int index) {
            return objects[index];
        }
    };
jList2.setModel(listmodel);`
```

Comment: See [this](http://www.javaprogrammingforums.com/awt-java-swing/23191-adding-items-jlist-using-jcombobox-problem-avoiding-duplicates.html) for help.

Comment: A one-column `JTable` makes the required cell editor easier.